# How can I expose a std::vector<std::string> via an extern "C" ABI?

Tags: c++, char, c-strings

I'm looking for the right way to access a vector of strings via a C ABI. My code looks broadly like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

// A C++ class containing information in a std::vector<std::string> that I want to expose in C (for eventually exporting to python via shared library)

class AVectorOfStrings{
private:
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
public:
    explicit AVectorOfStrings(std::vector<std::string> vec) : vec(std::move(vec)){}

    const vector<std::string> &getVec() const {
        return vec;
    }

    void setVec(const vector<std::string> &vec) {
        AVectorOfStrings::vec = vec;
    }
};

extern "C" {
    // function for accessing the strings
    char** getArrayOfCharStars(AVectorOfStrings* vec){
        std::vector<std::string> strings = vec->getVec();
        char **arr = (char **) malloc(strings.size() * sizeof(char *));

        for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(strings[i].c_str()));
            strcpy(arr[i], strings[i].c_str());
        }
        return arr;
    }

}
// usage
int main(){

    std::vector<std::string> input = {"1string", "2string", "3string"};
    AVectorOfStrings vec(input);

    char** arr = getArrayOfCharStars(&vec);

    // A bunch of attempts to access the three strings. 
    std::cout << *arr << std::endl;
    std::cout << *arr[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(arr[1]) << std::endl;
    std::cout << **arr << std::endl;

    return 0;
};
```

This code returns the following

```
1string
2
2
1
```

What would be the right way to get access to these strings? More generally, is this the right approach for handling an array of strings in C++? My end goal is just to have the strings stored in a way that I can access in Python using `ctypes`.

Comment: The second `sizeof` should be `strlen(...) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it would be much more simple to use `pybind` and wrap the stl `std::vector<std::string>` directly. You have an example of that [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#automatic-conversion).

```
class AVectorOfStrings {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
};

/* ... binding code ... */

py::class_<AVectorOfStrings>(m, "AVectorOfStrings")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def_readwrite("contents", &AVectorOfStrings::contents);
```

Comment: Very interesting. I'm already (and have to) work with `ctypes` but perhaps these two mechanisms of communication are not mutually exclusive.